# gbak installed through firebird3.0-utils restoring a backup gives error when trying to open it

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

I have a backup file. I did `apt-get install firebird3.0-utils` to get `gbak`. I am restored a database that is Firebird 2.5 and I am also running Firebird 2.5 locally. When I try to open the restored database, I get an error "structure found 12.1, support 11.2."

Put it another way

1. I have Firebird 2.5 running locally
2. database.bkp (file to restore, Firebid 2.5)
3. `apt get install firebird3.0-utils`
4. I executed gbak to restore the database, fdb generated successfully
5. But I cannot open the file "structure found 12.1, support 11.2."

Answer (score 1):

When you restored the database using a Firebird 3.0 gbak, it restored the database in Firebird 3.0 format (ODS 12.1 in your case), and Firebird 2.5 cannot read that ODS format (it supports versions 10 - 11.2). You need to restore using a Firebird 2.5 gbak, or upgrade to Firebird 3.0.

You can also use the service manager to restore the database using your Firebird server itself. The `gbak` tool allows you to do this type of restore through the service manager, see [Remote Backups & Restores](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/firebirddocs/gbak/firebird-gbak.html#gbak-recipies-remote) in the gbak documentation.

Other alternatives are using tools that utilize the service manager (e.g. FlameRobin, `fbsvcmgr`, and others), or libraries that provide programmatic access to this (e.g. Jaybird's `FBBackupManager`, FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient's `FbBackup` and others).